# Start an instance of an Activity

Tags: java, android-activity

```
startActivity(mMainActivity);
```

When I hover over  startActivity(mMainActivity); is says startActivity (Android.content.intent) cannot be applied to (Android.App.Activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that you need to pass the intent and not the activity class..

Comment: correct, but I WANT to pass the activity class. is there someway to do that?

Comment: u cannot pass an activity but pass the context.